# new to javascript code and having some issues already

Tags: javascript

i have this code: the idea is to print the list of the 10 random numbers and then add 6 to each item on the list and finally print new list with the new numbers after the additions: I've tried several modification but all of them are failing, any ideas??

```
var myArray = [];
appendItem(myArray, randomNumber(1,10));
appendItem(myArray, randomNumber(1,10));
appendItem(myArray, randomNumber(1,10));
appendItem(myArray, randomNumber(1,10));


console.log("Before: " + myArray);

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.lenght; i++) {
 myArray = [i] + 5;
}

console.log("After: " + myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

one solution can be

```
let myArray  = []
for (let i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {
    myArray.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 5);
} 
console.log(myArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to help you along your way...
It looks like you're using borrowed code somewhere, because `randomNumber` is not a native JavaScript function.

So, first to get a random number, you can read more about `Math.random()` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

`Math.random()` natively provides a decimal number between 0 and 1 (0.4, 0.67, 0.321 ...) To get a range, you multiply your answer by the maximum number for the range.  And then commonly you want to wrap that in a `Math.floor()` method to trim the decimal points (this is just a Math method that all it does is trim off anything that's a decimal point and provides a whole number)

W3C is a good place to start to read up about arrays:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp
The common convention for adding elements to an array is to use `.push()` but you can look into `.pop()` and `.filter()` and `.map()` and there's just a ton of helpful methods attached to JavaScript arrays :)

```js
/*
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random
*/
let originalArray = [];
let plusSixArray  = [];

let max = 10; // set the range for your random number
// max = 10 will let the range be from 0 - 9
// max = 273 will let the range be from 0 - 272

for( var i=0; i<10; i++ ){
  let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1;
  // adding 1 to the end gives you a range between 1 - 10
  originalArray.push( number );
  // since you're already in a loop, just add the 6
  plusSixArray.push( number + 6 );
}

console.log( originalArray );
console.log( plusSixArray );
```